# How to add text effects in GIMP 2.8?

Tags: gimp

Is there any text effects option for GIMP 2.8 ? Like add material, fire, glow etc Or even simpler ones like gradient or different colours in same letter.

I am open to add as many text effects plugins as possible. It will be nice if I can do this through terminal.

Comment: Look at [texteffectsforgimp.wordpress.com](http://texteffectsforgimp.wordpress.com/) and [tutorialized.com](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/Gimp/Text-Effects/1) Hope it's what you're looking for. These are tutorials (alot of them), about plugins, sorry I don't know.

Comment: Thanks. It is sad that GIMP does not have simple apply mode. We have to spend half an hour to create a glow :(

Answer (score 0):

You can color the individual letters manually by selecting a letter and choosing a color from the on-canvas text tool.

If you want fancy stuff, use the `file -> create -> logo` items. (I'm not sure about the exact names, my GIMP is translated.) They create new images, but you can merge all the layers (or only some of them) and copy the resulting layer onto the image you are editing.

IDK about command line GIMP usage.